# Package Name Info for Android Apps

Tags: applications

Hi I would like to know if there exists a website where in once you enter the name of the android app gives you all the related info of that particular app. I am especially interested in the `Package Name` of the app.

I know about the site `Droid Icon`([Link](http://activities.droidicon.com/)) and also the app called Package Name viewer and have tried both out.

The App `package name viewer` works excellently but only returns the info of the apps installed on my device and not all. So for the information I need I have to install the app first. Which is a tedious job if we need to do it for 10 or more apps.

Droid Icon web site gives numerous package names which are at times not correct.

So I would like to know if there exists another source for my specific requirement.( i.e package names).

Comment: The problem is that the human-readable name of an app is different in different languages, and isn't necessarily unique, so there's no reliable way to find the particular app you're looking for. Have you considered just doing a search on Google Play?

Comment: That is exactly why Package Names are unique. Name of the app may vary but the package name of the app stays the same. Thats why my aim is to find the package names. Now say I have 10 apps on my android phone. I will get their package names instantly using the package name viewer app. but what if i want to know the package names of 50 or say 100 apps? then it doesnt make sense installing each and every app on my phone just to find that one detail(pkg name) I am looking for.

Comment: And if you read Dan's comment again: "human readable names" are not unique, while package names are. So you can easily lookup the package name to find out the human-readable name – but not vice-versa. Try e.g. "Quick Dial". There are hundreds of apps using that name. All you can do is searching Play or Appbrain and see what turns up. No unique way, as that's technical impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up my own example from above comment on the question: Simply use your Google-Fu. Here's mine:

[intitle:"quick dial" site:play.google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:"quick+dial"+site:play.google.com)

Hits: 197. Now try that for 50 or 100 apps. For most of them, the result list will be shorter – if the devs thought of more unique names:

[intitle:"secure backup" site:play.google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:"secure+backup"+site:play.google.com)

Hits: 3, Exact hits: 1 (easy to tell by the title). Hover the URL: `com.sentinal`.

[intitle:"stripsearch" site:play.google.com] Yuck. Got me. Need to improve my Google-Fu:

[intitle:"stripsearch" site:play.google.com inurl:"store/apps"](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:"stripsearch"+site:play.google.com+inurl:"store/apps"): 1 hit. Exact. Correct.

Repeating #1 with the new foo: Much better, just 196 hits (oops).

---

I just notice I forgot the explanation:

- `intitle`: What appears as `<TITLE>` in your browser window's title bar. With *Google Play Store*, this includes the *App name* – so this is where we put our search term
- `site`: Restrict the search to a specific site. In our case, that's the *Google Play Store* – where most apps are listed. Same could be done with e.g. *Aptoide* (e.g. `intitle:"quick dial" site:store.aptoide.com` returns 3 hits) – but wouldn't work with *F-Droid* (the `<TITLE>` with them is always 'F-Droid', no matter what)
- `inurl`: a string being part of the URL. I used this in my example to fix my search to apps – without that, results included *Google Books*, *Google Music*, and probably even more (everything sold via *Google Play Store*)

Comment: For readers: Google also offers an interface for advanced searching. Find it [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890). And then there are [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) to make the life (and search) easier. Did I mention [Google Dorks](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/using-google-dorks-for-a-specific-site)?