# How to find out the package name of an Android app, without ADB nor installing apps

Tags: applications

My friend just showed me a really useful app. I want to install it too, but the app's name is very generic and there is no app with this name in any app store nor on the web. Knowing the **package name** of the app would help me find it.

How can I know the **package name** of an app?

- In Settings>App I only see the app's *name*.
- If it was my phone I would install [Applications Info](https://github.com/MajeurAndroid/Android-Applications-Info) and read the package name. Unfortunately I can't install anything on the phone. Understandably, my friend does not allow me to enable developer options, nor to connect any cable to it.
- The phone otherwise only has stock apps.

Latest Android.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/90141. Btw, the correct term is "package name", you might use that keyword to search for related existing questions.

Comment: That question specifies "via ADB". So any answer there is not a valid answer here, and vice versa. So I don't think it is a duplicate. Thanks for the terminology tip, I fixed my question :-)

Comment: If I understood correctly, then the restriction on this question is: stock, fully-locked (cannot install/side-load apps, cannot use USB debug, not rooted, etc.) Android devices? If that's the case... based on my experience, it's almost impossible to get the package name, surprisingly... hopefully others know the solution.

Comment: Ugly way: Let your friend install Helium Backup, create a backup of that app, and see how the backup was named. Or use an "[app inspector](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_inspect)" (link goes to my corresponding app listing). Or shock him and let him use [ClassyShark3xodus](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.oF2pks.classyshark3xodus/), which doesn't only show the package name but also the trackers inside ;) Without installing an app you can only hope to open it in play store (web site, "id" part of the URL).

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes exactly. I hope Izzy knows some trick either via settings or via the Play store app or something else :-)

Comment: Re: Izzy's comment on "open it in Play Store", related Q&A: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78318/package-name-info-for-android-apps. Also try searching the same app name on Appbrain just in case the app has been taken down from Play Store. But otherwise, if nothing comes up, then it might be a proprietary app specific to certain vendors/manufacturers.

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately I can't install anything on the phone, and it has only has stock apps, so no Titanium/Helium/etc.

Comment: PS: Open in play store (app) might be helpful as well. Write down the name of the developer, and use that to show all his/her apps: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<url+encoded+name>`. If any of that constitutes an answer in your eyes, let me know :)

Comment: There is a browser app, so that's definitely an idea. Please note that "there is no app with this name in any app store". I suspect the app was removed from Play. Or maybe it was installed another way, even possibly via APK by a pre-owner who then would have disabled developer options.

Comment: In that case you're out of luck. The only way to get the app then would be to extract it from his device – which you cannot do as you can neither install an "app extractor"/backup, nor use ADB :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to that – depending on what you have access to. I'll include those not working for you as they might work for others:

- Most obvious: use an [app inspector](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_inspect) (link goes to my corresponding app list). Won't work for you as you cannot install any app.
- Not that obvious, but with helpful side effect: install [ClassyShark3xodus](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.oF2pks.classyshark3xodus/) from F-Droid. Not only shows the package name but also the trackers contained in apps. Again, needs installing an app.
- Another one with helpful side effects: installing Helium Backup and inspecting the backup file name. Doesn't work for you either, unfortunately.
- Native method: Open in Play Store, ideally in the web page. Find the package name in the URL's `id` parameter. If in app, use the developer's name to list all apps made by them: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<url+encoded+name>`.

If the app is not available in any of the app stores available on the device (often happens with vendor specific pre-installed apps), you're out of luck: you cannot even extract the APK from your friend's device if (s)he doesn't let you install an APK extractor or enable ADB (with ADB, you could e.g. use Adebar's [getapk](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar/src/branch/master/tools/getapk) script to extract all or specific apps).